# How to open canvas app as a popup from VF page?

Tags: visualforce, session, canvas

I am facing the below issue on opening a canvas app as a pop up from VF page.

> There was an error rendering Force.com Canvas application . Your
>   browsing session has ended or is invalid. Please re-login to
>   Salesforce.com again.

Here is my code:

```
<apex:outputPanel id="popup">
<apex:outputPanel styleClass="popupBg" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}"/>
<apex:outputPanel styleClass="popup" layout="block" rendered="{!displayPopUp}">
  Popup window
<apex:canvasApp applicationName="Spring_MVC_App" parameters="{param1:'value2'}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Hide" action="{!closePopup}" rerender="popup"/>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide a little more information on how you are generating your pop-up?

If you are just ejecting a new browser window and not creating the popup in VF, this will likely not work since Canvas requires the session information from salesforce.com.

If you can post the full VF page and any controllers or extensions you use, I can confirm.

Thanks